# Adding multiple Textviews as a ListView item

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-adapter

In android, I am trying to create a ListView with each item being 3 textviews. When I run my program, It shows a white page (empty list). As a beginner, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is my custom adapter and a custom object class.

```
class CustomObject {

    private String title;
    private String date;
    private String body;

    public CustomObject(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
        this.title = prop1;
        this.date = prop2;
        this.body=prop3;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getBody(){
        return body;
    }

}


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomObject> objects;
    private Activity activity;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        TextView dateTextView;
        TextView bodyTextView;
    }


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomObject> objects, Activity activity) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.activity= activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomObject getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null); //NOT SURE


            holder.titleTextView = new TextView(activity);
            //holder.titleTextView.setText(titleList.get(i));
            holder.titleTextView.setTextSize(14);
            holder.titleTextView.setTypeface(holder.titleTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD); //title in bold
            holder.titleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


            holder.dateTextView = new TextView(activity);
            //tvDate[i].setText(dateList.get(i));
            holder.dateTextView.setTextSize(14);
            holder.dateTextView.setTypeface(holder.dateTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC); //Date in ITALIC
            holder.dateTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            holder.bodyTextView = new TextView(activity);
            //holder.bodyTextView.setText(textList.get(i));
            holder.bodyTextView.setTextSize(14);
            holder.bodyTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.titleTextView.setText(objects.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.dateTextView.setText(objects.get(position).getDate());
        holder.bodyTextView.setText(objects.get(position).getBody());
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Below is a method that creates and displays the listView

```
  private void displayNews()
    {

        ListView listView =  new ListView(activity);
        //listView.setLayoutParams();


        ArrayList<CustomObject> objects = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
        for(int i=0; i<titleList.size(); i++)
            objects.add(new CustomObject(titleList.get(i), dateList.get(i),textList.get(i) ));
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(activity, objects, activity);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        //THE WHOLE VIEW
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(activity);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(activity);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        ll.addView(listView,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); //adding


        sv.addView(ll);//adding the layout view to the scorllable view
        activity.setContentView(sv);//adding the scrollable view to the activity :)

    }
```

Below is *activity_listview.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="right">
</TextView>
```

Comment: try to add all three textview in your xml and get the reference in your adapter class. do not create new textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `activity_listview.xml` for example like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip"
       android:textSize="16dip"
       android:textStyle="bold">
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/txtDate"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip"
       android:textSize="16dip">
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/txtBody"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip"
       android:textSize="16dip">
   </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Change code that inflates the view and initialize `ViewHolder` instance:

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);

holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
holder.dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
holder.bodyTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBody);
```

Note that `R.id.txtTitle`, `R.id.txtDate` and `R.id.txtBody` corresponds with `android:id="@+id/txtTitle"`, `android:id="@+id/txtDate"`, `android:id="@+id/txtBody"` in layout file (activity_listview.xml).

**Update:**

I edit layout file. You can try to design the layout using GUI in Android Studio.

Comment: There is an improvement but now I can only see one line, which is the title of the first element.

Comment: I agree the XML design needs a fixing, but still, I am getting only the first item. Something in the code needs to be updated/added. Can you please check?

Comment: I fixed the layout design. Now, the problem is that only 1 item is displayed in the list.

Comment: For some reason, my getView is getting called only for position 0 !

Comment: make sure `return objects.size();` does return the actual number of objects. Also objects array content depends on  `titleList.size()` as you initialize based on its content. Make dure that titleList does contain correct list.

Comment: It is working fine now. The fix was NOT to add the listview to the scroll view nor to the linear layout. Just make it as a Content View. It would be good to add this note in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create text views dynamically so you must add them to viewgroup.
Similar to what you did with your listview in this line:

```
ll.addView(listView,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); //adding
```

Just create new ViewGroup (LinearLayout, Relative Layout etc..) and add your textviews.

Hope it helps!